# Problem with connection to external server in java app

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

I have problem while i try to connect to my database in external server. Everything is fine when i use localhost but when I try to connect to server i have an error. I also use xampp, maybe problem is here? 
Do you have some idea about this problem, and maybe some solution? 
Here is my connection class and in the bottom is an error that I get:

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MakeConnection {
    private static Connection connection = null;
    Boolean error = false;
    private static String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://server_name:3306/db_name";
    private static String user = "user";
    private static String password = "password";

    MakeConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException{
        this.connection = connection;
    try {
        getConnection();
        System.out.print("Connected to the data base in MakeConnection");       
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            error = true;
            System.out.print("Error in connection in MakeConnection consturctor" + e.getMessage());
            }

        finally{
        if(connection!=null)            connection.close();
        if(error)                       System.out.print("Problem with connection");
        else                            System.out.print("Program finished");
        }
    }
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,user,password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.MakeConnection.getConnection(MakeConnection.java:34)
    at jdbc.MakeConnection.<init>(MakeConnection.java:17)
    at jdbc.UsersCheck.<init>(UsersCheck.java:16)
    at GUI.LogInFrame.<init>(LogInFrame.java:51)
    at GUI.LogInFrame.main(LogInFrame.java:41)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:150)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:947)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:817)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 13 more
Connected to the data base in MakeConnectionProgram finishedcom.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Connected to the data base in MakeConnectionProgram finished    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:447)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.MakeConnection.getConnection(MakeConnection.java:34)
    at jdbc.MakeConnection.<init>(MakeConnection.java:17)
    at jdbc.UsersCheck.<init>(UsersCheck.java:16)
    at GUI.LogInFrame.createDesign(LogInFrame.java:104)
    at GUI.LogInFrame.<init>(LogInFrame.java:52)
    at GUI.LogInFrame.main(LogInFrame.java:41)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:150)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:947)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:817)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to that server from your machine not using java?

Comment: I connected by phpMyAdmin but when i would like to make connection in MySQL workbench i have an error but different type. Error message says that I can't connect to this DataBase server. But I think that this is different problem because when I try to connect to different serwer to other host account I also have this strange error in java (but after few second after application start working... idk why)